# django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader won't search in installed_apps for templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When the app is looking for templates, the django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader  loader won't look up for templates in apps it's only searching for templates in the virtual enviroment's libraries. On my windows machine it appears to be working fine however on linux it seems to be facing this issue.

The html file I'm trying to render is in $PROJECT/main/Templates/index.html normally the loader should search for it.

settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for testproject project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-$##t7qug+=d)poxawz=v3!7r@-70-z!qtmcp-qnq$s81*aj!fa'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main'
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"Templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'testapp',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }   
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

The following error occurred:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/user/Desktop/working_directory/work/DjangoTest/testproject/Templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

Full Error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7zPI.png)

Comment: just a suggestion,  verify if the template folder name is "Templates" not "templates", it is case sensitive

Comment: "_On my windows machine it appears to be working fine however on linux it seems to be facing this issue_", considering that on Linux (it is not in Windows), the file system is case sensitive (as stated above by @tahamaatof) it appears that should be your problem.

Comment: it actually is Templates instead of templates, that's not the case. Nonetheless it should mention that it searched in these directories(even though it starts with a lowercase letter instead of uppercase) next to the "Source does not exist" error like it did with the above. https://i.imgur.com/qHqrXZb.png

Comment: @varprp100 you can name the directories you specify in `DIRS` part of the setting anything you want, **but** Django will search only for the directory `templates` (all lowercase) in the installed apps. Rename it to be lowercase and you will see that it now works.